# Square root in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a vue.js app. I've got a problem with my 'results' method - it should square root the number passed in input. What can I do to make it work?

HTML:

```
  <div id="app" class="container">
      <button class="root" @click="filter()">Root Extraction</button>
    <template v-if="rootObject.squareRoot">
      <div class="rootBox">
        <h1>Type a random number to square root it!</h1>
        <input id="number" type="number" min="0"/>
        <button id="button" @click="results()" type="button">Count it</button>
        <h1 id="result"></h1>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
```

Js:

```
var result = document.getElementById("result");
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rootObject: {
      squareRoot: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    results: function () {
      result.innerHTML = "Square rooted number is: " + Math.sqrt(document.getElementById("number").value);
    },
    filter: function() {
      this.rootObject.squareRoot = !this.rootObject.squareRoot;
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the simple answer to your question is that you should not use "document.getBy..." with vuejs, it leads to funky results. Use the VueJs built-in interpolation system, it will ensure that your application is reactive.

Here is a fiddler with a working version of your code https://jsfiddle.net/49gptnad/784/

here is the code:
**HTML**

```
<div id="app" class="container">
  <button class="root" @click="toggleSquareRoot()">Root Extraction</button>
  <template v-if="squareRootOpen">
    <div class="rootBox">
      <h1>Type a random number to square root it!</h1>
      <input id="number" type="number" min="0"/>
      <button id="button" @click="computeResults()" type="button">Count it</button>
      <h1>{{results}}</h1>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // no need for data to be nested
    squareRootOpen: false,
    results: "n/a"
  },
  methods: {
    // compute the output and store it in VueJs
    computeResults: function () {
      this.results = Math.sqrt(document.getElementById("number").value)
    },
    toggleSquareRoot: function() {
      this.squareRootOpen = !this.squareRootOpen;
    }
  }
})
```

So a few notes on your code:

1. Use more verbose naming schemes. "filter" is not really descriptive of what the function is doing.
2. Read the documentation prior to posting on stackoverflow. VueJs actually did a great job covering this sort of concerns: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text
3. Learn proper HTML syntax, you had quite a few typos there (with  having no room where it was and  not needing a close tag)

Comment: Thank you very much. HTML typos were just by accident.